# Callback function in React doesn't work (State still the same)

Tags: reactjs, callback, parent-child, state, onchange

I'm calling this function:

```
  dataChanged(data) {
    // data = { description: "New validated text comes here" } 
    // Update your model from here 
    console.log(data)
    this.setState({data}, function(){
        console.log(this.state)
    })
  }
```

But I still have the same state...

the element from I'm calling it :

```
        <CollapsibleItem header="My Goal" icon='public'>
              <InlineEdit
              validate={this.customValidateText}
              activeClassName="editing"
              text={this.state.goal}
              paramName="goal"
              change={this.componentDidUpdate}
            />
        </CollapsibleItem>
```

I've also tried call this function  instead :

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if (this.state.goal !== prevState.goal) {
       console.log(this.state) 
      }
    }
```

Didn't work too

Comment: Can you post the output of your log statements? Try removing the brackets from {data}. Just do this.setState(data, function...

Comment: only  removing the brackets worked! Thank you!!